# Pagination on child category returns 404

Tags: categories, pagination

Can anyone figure out why viewing pages in my child categories results in a 404, when the same `$paged` code works fine for my index file? This is inside of my category-15.php (it's to affect all child categories under parent category ID 15).

```
  <?php
    $PostNum = 1;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $CustomQueryIdentifier = new WP_Query($args);
  ?>

    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_category(' '); ?></a></h1>

    <?php
      if ( $CustomQueryIdentifier->have_posts() ) : while ( $CustomQueryIdentifier->have_posts() ) : $CustomQueryIdentifier->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="container">
      <p class="number"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php $postnumber = $CustomQueryIdentifier->current_post; echo $postnumber+1 ?></a></p>
      <?php the_content(''); ?>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

  <div class="navigation">
    <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $CustomQueryIdentifier->max_num_pages) ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
  </div>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: How many posts are in the category you are viewing, and what is the posts per page value in the reading settings page? If you are trying to view a page beyond the number of posts you have, you get a 404.

Comment: @Milo The category has 3 posts. Viewing the first page shows only 2 posts (as expected). The reading settings has 5 posts per page, and the query above is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions here regarding pagination, it is definitely one of the least understood aspects of how WordPress works internally.

To understand why you get 404s, we'll start by looking at the [Action Reference in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see the process WordPress follows for each request.

The process begins by loading up the plugins and theme, and doing some initialization to set everything up, etc., etc.. The part we are interested in begins at `parse_request`, when WordPress determines what sort of page is being requested, and `parse_query`, when the query variables are set to generate the [Main Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query).

The next action is [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), which gives us an opportunity to modify the main query. This is where you want to execute your own code to change the main query, for example, setting a different `posts_per_page` value (hint, hint).

Then we reach the `wp` action, after the main query is run, and finally the important bit of info in this explanation- the `template_redirect` action. This is the action where WordPress determines what template to load, based on the results of the main query. If it's a category, the category template is loaded, if it's an archive, the archive template is loaded, and **if it's a 404- the 404 template is loaded**.

Yes, bold text means that last part was important, and hopefully we are beginning to understand the problem. WordPress decided the request is a 404 before your template was ever loaded. Whatever the results you get by running queries in the template are irrelevant. If the main query doesn't return post(s), it's a 404.

In your case, you're getting a 404 because the main query is loading 5 posts per page, and you only have 3, there is no second page as far as the main query is concerned.

( But wait a minute, you say, why does it work on some pages and not others? Yes, confusingly enough it won't always result in a 404, for example when the request is a singular page. )

The solution to your category problem was hinted at earlier in the story- if you want to modify the query, use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) *before* the main query is run.

```
// modify main query for category ID 15 and all its children
function wpd_category_query( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_category() ) {
        $parent = 15; // your parent category
        $categories = get_term_children( $parent, 'category' );
        $categories[] = $parent;

        if( is_category( $categories ) ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpd_category_query' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic writeup! I understand the problem quite a bit better because of it. I plugged in your code and now it's no longer returning a 404, but instead it's returning the same posts in page 2 (Only ever shows posts 1-2 and doesn't swap to post 3).

Comment: that shouldn't be the case, there must be something else modifying the query. make sure there's nothing overwriting `$wp_query` in the template- no calls to `query_posts`. try an unedited template file and disable plugins to test. there may also be something else in `functions.php` changing the query.