# Pagination in custom query in a category page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, query, plugin-wp-pagenavi

In a category (I create category-123.php), I'd like to create a new custom query in order to show all the posts that have right parameters (custom fields).

```
<?php $today = date("Ymd"); 
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$query = new WP_Query(array(
                      'meta_key'=>'duedate',
                      'meta_value'=>$today,'meta_compare'=>'>=' , 
                      'paged' => $paged,
                      'posts_per_page'=>'20') 
                     );
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_title();?><br />

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $query )); ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In this case, only first page is working... the others are 404 error. Could you please help me to understand where I'm wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please properly indent your code and make use of line breaks. It is hard to read your code and to debug it

Comment: Search for `pre_get_posts` instead of creating another query. 404 is determined by the main query, has nothing to do with your custom query.

Comment: Ok, better indent

Comment: @Milo, could you please explain better? I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303743/new-wp-query-or-pre-get-posts-to-view-all-posts-for-custom-post-type) but unfortunately I cannot understand how to use `pre_get_posts`. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pagination on child category returns 404](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152972/pagination-on-child-category-returns-404)

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit more readable now. Can be improved though. :-). You can also check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545)

Comment: ok, just to test it I add to my funcions.php this code: `function my_func( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_category( '637' )) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '600' );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_func' );`

category 637 for which I'd like to alter the query, but the query in this way can't find post. category 600 has 20 posts.

Comment: @Milo, I don't think it is that your answer is completely suitable to my case. In category 600 (that I want a different query) is empty (no posts inside)...

Comment: you're trying to make one category display posts from a different category? the code in your comment doesn't match the code in your original question, so it's not clear what you are attempting, or why.

Comment: My final result would be to show all the posts in my website in the category page of category id 637... so for example: http://www.mysite.com/category/category637 is the list of all posts, this is why I have a wp_query...

Answer (score 0):

Meta query must be done with a nested array. So it may look more like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
                array( 
                    'meta_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'key' => 'duedate',
                                            'value'=> $today,
                                            'compare' => '>=', 
                                        ),
                    ),
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page'=>'20'
                )
            );
```